# python - return function -- get variable name

Tags: python-2.7

I was wondering if it is possible to use the return function and get the variable name

p.s ^ help to rephrase the above line

If you do not understand, here is the code:

```
def foo():

    return <get variable name here>

a = foo()
```

Therefore, it will return 'a' to the variable a, 'b' to the variable b and so on, which means

the variable will contain its name.

Is there a function to return the variable's name ?

Comment: I've answered you below, but unless you have good reason for asking this, I'll downvote this question. This is very bad programming practice, and my answer covers how to do it just for you to get grip of some builtins, not for real usage.

Answer (score 1):

Can you write what you need that for?

There is no way to do that as you wish. But you can:
- do that without return, just define variable outside the function
- return a dict like {'a': variable}
There are other possibilities, depends only what are you want to do.

Comment: Actually, we have acces for such dict in runtime - with `locals()` and `globals()` builtins.

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT**: this is ugly and is probably WRONG way to do what you wanna do. Show us the whole use case, so we'll be able to help you choose better solution.

It is almost possible. Lets consider this:

```
g = True

def foo(val):
    a = 5
    b = "abc"
    return XXX
```

And you want `XXX` to be `"g"` when val is `True`, `"a"` if `val` is `5` and `"b"` when `val` is `"abc"`. You can inspect local and global variables with `locals()` and `globals()`:

```
g = True

def foo(val):
    a = 5
    b = "abc"
    for k, v in locals().iteritems():   # this will iterate over {"a": 5, "b": "abc"}
        if v == var: # or "is" if you want identity
            return k
    for k, v in globals().iteritems():  # this will iterate over {"g": True, "foo": <this function>}
        if v == var: # or "is" if you want identity
            return k
     return <default value>
```

Of course, there may be many names with the same value, and random of that names will be returned, if any. For example, it both `a` and `b` would have value `5` and you pass `5` as `val`, there is no way to tell which of them will be returned.

**I REPEAT. WHATEVER YOU'RE TRYING TO DO, THIS IS WRONG (WITH 99.999% PROBABILITY). THERE ARE SOME REALLY SPECIAL SITUATIONS, WHEN `locals()` AND `globals()` MAY COME HANDY, BUT I DON'T THINK THIS IS ONE OF THOSE SITUATIONS.**

== EDIT ==

I finally understood that you want to get the name of variable you're binding. Probably some tampering with stack trace could help you, but again - this is WRONG.